# How to work with QT (cross platform development) designer?

Tags: qt, mobile

I am new to Qt I created my first form and I want to look this on My mobile how can I, I mean how can i run this or create sis file for this that I can look this on my mobile..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to be RTFMy, but I suggest that you start by looking at the examples that come with Qt and go from there.
Also Qt ships with a lot of useful documentation and tutorials which are right at your fingertips if you use Qt Creator.

Comment: I just created a new form using Qt designer and I want to run it to know how it looks??? but not found any where..